# Reading binary data from file in Python and passing it to a C++ function

Tags: python, cython

How to pass binary data loaded by Python directly from a file to a C++ function taking data pointer and size called in a Cython module?

```
loadFromMemory(const void*, size_t)
```

This is probably how it would look like in pure Python:

```
with open('file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    loadFromMemory(data, len(data))  # How to do this in Cython?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a two step cast first to a `char*` (which Cython can get easily from a string) and then second to reinterpret that as a `void*`:

```
loadFromMemory(<void*>(<char*>data), len(data))
```

This does assume that `loadFromMemory` doesn't expect the pointer to remain valid after the function call (Cython won't manage the memory for you automatically, and it'll be freed when `data` is destroyed).

(Skipping the cast to `char*` and just casting straight to a `void*` will take the address of the Python object, which isn't what you want)